# How do I split a terminal into two "views" (or two parts) so I don't have to scroll up / down?

Tags: gnome-terminal, terminator, tmux, gnu-screen

Nginx log is being generated real time with 
    watch -n 1 "tail -n 1000 nginx.log"

I want it to appear on the right side of the terminal. How can I make 2 or 3 screens? I have a very wide screen (not wide enough to be vertical but wide enough to show a lot of empty spaces on the right side using the command above). I would like to see the first few characters of the output above only so I don't mind if total length is cut off.

Please give a clue on what I should do to achieve this as I can't find online. The best I can do is "screen" and tmux but both of them does not seem to have such a feature, to split a continuous window into two parts vertically. Please help. Thanks.

I would like to not needing to scroll up. So as much information as possible on one screen with the data overflowing on the other split screens on the same thing. Not opening different screens for different things.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running such simple commands as a `tail`, you can just open multiple terminal windows or tabs, or split the `terminator` window, and execute `tail` in more of them. Then you can scroll back in one and not scroll back in another.

KDE's terminal emulator `konsole` has a "Split View" feature, you can have two or more viewpoints to the same terminal. VTE-based terminal emulators such as GNOME Terminal or Terminator [don't support this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103770).

Comment: I would like to not needing to scroll up. So as much information as possible on one screen with the data overflowing on the other split screens on the same thing. Not opening different screens for different things.

Comment: Why do you split the screen at all, then? I guess I don't understand you. Could you maybe create mock screenshot demonstrating what you wish to have?